# How to update the java runtime version from 7 to 8

Tags: spring, eclipse

I am trying to run spring sts tool eclpise. Installed java (jdk and jre) 8 but the runtime is still taken as 7. I get a pop up saying version is wrong and cant run the sts tool.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In window / preferences / Installed JREs you need to have the JDK1.8 as the default set up.

Comment: Thanks jaspreet , but that can only be done if the software is opened. When I run the exe it simply gives the error and doesn't gen opened. :( I have uninstalled jdk 1.7 and jre 1.7 from my machine. Still the jre is taken as 1.7